# Read files from external storage in onCreate on marshmallow and above marshmallow devices

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to read the files from external storage in `onCreate` method by calling a method `LoadData()`. Here is my code.

```html
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//I tried declaring permissions before calling the file
//            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

//        LoadData(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

        LoadMyData(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);


}
```

This is how it should go:

`1.Open the app for the first time  --> Ask for permissions --> LoadData();
2.Open the app for the secondtime --> LoadData();`

This is how it is going: 

`1.Open the app for the first time  --> Ask for permissions ;(It is not calling LoadData())
2.Open the app for the second time --> LoadData();(For the second time it is calling LoadData())`

All the run-time permissions are declared properly. I know that `LoadData()` is not called the first time because, the permissions are not set yet. Is there a way out since I want LoadData() to be called on onCreate()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Marshmallow OS and above that you have to use this code to read or write any thing on external storage.

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

             if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            if (checkPermission()) {
                                      LoadMyData(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

                            } else {
                                requestPermission();
                            }
                        }
               }


                protected boolean checkPermission() {
                    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                protected void requestPermission() {

                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Write External Storage permission allows us to do store images. Please allow this permission in App Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 100);
                        }
                    }
                }

            @Override
            public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
                switch (requestCode) {
                    case 100:
                        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            LoadMyData(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
                        } else {
                            Log.e("value", "Permission Denied, You cannot use local drive .");
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `LoadData()` after user grants permissions - Your activity has to implement `ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback` and the results of permission requests will be delivered to its `onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])` method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It helped.